# Migrating Oracle geometry rows from geodetic to cartesian

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, spatial

I have a table (`granule`) with about 4 million unique geometry objects that currently have SRID = 8307.

I am trying to create a SECOND table, with the same data, but using a cartesian coordinate system.

I created the table,

```
create table granule_cartesian  (
        granule varchar(64) not null,
        SHAPE sdo_geometry NOT NULL );
```

and insert the proper geom_metadata

```
insert into user_sdo_geom_metadata (table_name, column_name, diminfo, srid)
values ( 'GRANULE_CARTESIAN', 'SHAPE',
        mdsys.sdo_dim_array(
                mdsys.sdo_dim_element('longitude', -180, 180, .5),
                mdsys.sdo_dim_element('latitude', -90, 90, .5)),
        null);
```

And now I want to copy the geometry contents of granule into granule_cartesian.

Obviously, the straight copy won't work because of SRID mismatch.

I can copy a few at a time by converting to wkt and back to geometry, stripping SRID:

```
insert into granule_cartesian
select  granule, 
        SDO_GEOMETRY(SDO_UTIL.TO_WKTGEOMETRY(shape), null) as shape
from    granule
where   platform = 'ZZ'; -- granule has a few other columns...
```

This works if I select a subset of granule table that is less than ~ 10k (about +/-10 minutes). Any more than 10K and the runs for hours, some times ungracefully disconnecting me.

It seems like there should be a way to do this WITHOUT doing <10K chunks. Besides taking FOREVER to actually migrate, this would pose a serious logistical nightmare on our active and dynamic production DB.  I've tried using SDO_CS.TRANSFORM like this:

```
SDO_CS.TRANSFORM(geom => shape, to_srid => null )
```

... But oracle will not accept a NULL SRID here:

```
 12:57:49  [SELECT - 0 row(s), 0.000 secs]  [Error Code: 1405, SQL State: 22002]  ORA-01405: fetched column value is NULL
ORA-06512: at "MDSYS.SDO_CS", line 114
ORA-06512: at "MDSYS.SDO_CS", line 152
ORA-06512: at "MDSYS.SDO_CS", line 5588
ORA-06512: at "MDSYS.SDO_CS", line 3064
```

SDO_CS.TRANSFORM_LAYER will refuse to accept a NULL SRID.

After extensive searching, I cannot find any method to do a streamline geodetic -> cartesian (SRID=NULL) conversion. Does anyone have any ideas besides brute force small batching?

***EDITS***

1) For Clarity, I understand that I could probably break it up using PL/SQL and do 450 blocks of 10K rows. But @ ~470 seconds per block, that is still 2.5 DAYS of execution. And that is a BEST case scenario. Changing projections/coordinate systems using `update granule set shape.srid = 8307` is FAST and EASY. Changing coordinate system from cartesian to geodetic using `insert into granule select SDO_CS.TRANSFORM(geom => shape, to_srid => 8307 ) ....` is FAST and EASY. What I'm looking for is an equally as simple/fast solution to go from geodetic to cartesian.

2) Tried to insert 300K as a test. It ran for approximately 10 hours and died like this:

```
 20:06:59  [INSERT - 0 row(s), 0.000 secs]  [Error Code: 4030, SQL State: 61000]  ORA-04030: out of process memory when trying to allocate 8080 bytes (joxcx callheap,f:CDUnscanned)
ORA-04030: out of process memory when trying to allocate 8080 bytes (joxcx callheap,f:CDUnscanned)
ORA-04030: out of process memory when trying to allocate 16328 bytes (koh-kghu sessi,kgmtlbdl)
ORA-06512: at "MDSYS.SDO_UTIL", line 2484
ORA-06512: at "MDSYS.SDO_UTIL", line 2511
```

This is a **beefy** enterprise level server with nothing but oracle. We recently had a Oracle Consultant (From Oracle) analyze all our DB systems (including this one). It was given a clean bill of health.

Comment: Creating a (possibly materialized) view "granule_cartesian" is no option, is it?

Comment: Ultimately the goal it to test the query performance of switching to the less accurate cartesian coordinate system. If we see enough performance benefit we can justify the degraded search accuracy. To this end we'd still like to compare apples to apples and comparing a table to a MatView wouldn't necessarily be a fair comparison. Even if we could show significant gains using a materialized view ( I'm not convinced the MatView would even build based on my current experiments! ), I still don't know how I could safely orchestrate the migrate.

Comment: Understood. (You might want to update your question accordingly.) Did you trace the performance degration for > 10k chunks to something in your environment? (Re-do log?) How many 10k batches would you have to do? PL/SQL perhaps?

Comment: If I try to do ALL 4,434,694 in 1 insert, using the WKT translation method, I do run out of re-do log after >24 hours of execution. Some times I get an ugly "SQL error 17410 No more data to read from socket" error. I am not a DBA, do not have DBA privs, any don't have access to DBA expertise beyond "Yeah, that is a tough problem...".

Comment: I do acknowledge that I could probably brute force it, either 1 granule at a time or 10k granules at a time ( 450 blocks of 10k @ 470 seconds per block). Probably. There is EXTENSIVE information about doing transformations between different geodetic SRID's, and from Cartesian to Geodetic. I can't believe there isn't a equally graceful ( Not PL/SQL Brute Force) and quick solution to go from geodetic to cartesian.

Answer (score 0):

Something is wrong with the database.  I have geom tables with 64 million rows ( every mapped road in North America - yes, Canada , US, and Mexico ) in them and I routinely perform sdo_anyinteract / sdo_contains queries and get 200 square mile responses in less than 5 seconds.

To do this first of all, drop any and all indexes and turn off logging on the target table or tablespace.  If you don't have the permissions ask your DBA but the command is:

```
alter table [table] nologging ; or alter tablespace [tablesspace] nologging ;
```

That should keep you for running out of redo space although if you are running out of redo space your DBA should fix that by adding redo segments.

Use a cursor because you have to add the SRID when taking in a WKT since the SRID has to be set on the SDO object.

```
declare

newGeom sdo_geometry ;

begin

 for rec in ( select statement ) loop

    newGeom := sdo_util.to_wktgeometry(rec.geom);
    newGeom.sdo_srid := [srid that matches the target ] ;

   insert into [table] (geom column, ... )values( newGeom, ... );

 end loop;

 commit ;

end ;
```

With 4 million rows this should happen in just a few minutes, if not your DB is seriously out of whack.

**MAKE SURE YOUR WORK WITH YOUR DBA**

When the process finishes then rebuild this domain indexes.  That might take a couple of hours.  Last time I did it on 64 million rows it took 3 days.  You have to understand that R-Trees are essentially indexes within indexes and use minimum bounding rectangles to get the speed and they take a **long** time to build since each insert represents traversal from the **root** of the index.

You can use things like **BULK COLLECT** but that is to complex for this place.  I suggest that if you don't already have one, get an Oracle account ( they are free ) and ask questions like this in the Oracle Forums under Database -> spatial

Comment: I'm not sure why you think there is something wrong with the DB based on what I have so far stated. A small search area like 200 Miles would return results from our big table (~22m shapes) in under a second no problem. Dealing with Satellite data, more common searches are regions the size of Alaska, Europe, or either polar region. Large region searches take minutes to hours to execute. A clone of our DB in Postgres/PostGIS can run the same large search regions in a fraction of a second in a cartesian coordinate system. We are attempting to see if Oracle will also.

Comment: Incidentally, I was able to use the pl/sql above (after removing the superfluous `sdo_util.to_wktgeometry()` ) to accomplish a quick population of the table. I was surprised the `newGeom.sdo_srid :=` syntax worked because transform() would not accept and srid of `null`.

Comment: As for DBA's, **I wish**. Unfortunately our DBAs (who work for a different organization with our university) strictly administer the DB. The do not consult on SQL, design, or implementations.

Comment: Tried to insert 300K as a test. It ran for approximately 10 hours and died like this:  -- That is why I think the DB is having problems.  Glad I could help.

Comment: Dear Brian, SRID's tell the system how to reference your geometries to the globe.  To change the SRID of a geom object you have to disconnect it from the underlying table and column.  Hence the code I gave you.  If it works, as you say it did, and it WILL work without the modifications you made, then please mark my answer as correct.  P.S. Pushing out to a WKT removes all notions of SRID which is how the data is projected.

Comment: Actaully, no, the way you wrote it **WILL NOT** work. My geom column `shape` is already a sdo_geometry object, which is clear from the explanation. The code as you wrote it throws the following error:  `07:15:32  [DECLARE - 0 row(s), 0.000 secs]  [Error Code: 6550, SQL State: 65000]  ORA-06550: line 9, column 16:
PLS-00382: expression is of wrong type
ORA-06550: line 9, column 5:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored` That is why I put forth the edit to correct that error.

Comment: I'm aware what the to_wkt syntax does, which is why I corrected your error. And FUTHER, you are also wrong that you need to "disconnect" the geometry from the table to change the SRID, there are NUMEROUS ways to **CHANGE** the SRID without such a brute force method: `SDO_CS.TRANSFORM`, `SDO_CS.TRANSFORM_LAYER`, as well as a straight up `update ... geom.srid = ###`, all of which are extensively covered in documentation, on this site, and others.  You're 100% missing the point. I'm not changing the SRID, I'm **REMOVING** the SRID. I am changing the whole coordinate system, not the projection!

Comment: Changing from SRID to SRID is like changing octane in your pump gas. It is essentially still the same thing. Changing coordinate systems ( SRID = NULL is CARTESIAN, SRID != NULL is GEODETIC) is like changing from a gasoline car to an electric car. The math is COMPLETELY deferent. Its flat plane with straight lines, where as geodetic is a round ball with great arcs.

Answer (score 0):

BrianB,
sorry, I just can't understand what are you trying to do with SDO_GEOMETRY(SDO_UTIL.TO_WKTGEOMETRY(shape), null) conversion. If I get it right, the resulting geometry will have the same geometry type, points, segments and ordinates as in source shape.
So, if this is true, you can use one of those:

```
create table granule_cartesian  (
    granule varchar(64) not null,
    SHAPE sdo_geometry NOT NULL );

insert into granule_cartesian
select  granule, shape
from    granule
where   platform = 'ZZ'; -- granule has a few other columns... 

update granule_cartesian t
set t.shape.sdo_srid = null;

insert into user_sdo_geom_metadata (table_name, column_name, diminfo, srid)
values ( 'GRANULE_CARTESIAN', 'SHAPE',
    mdsys.sdo_dim_array(
            mdsys.sdo_dim_element('longitude', -180, 180, .5),
            mdsys.sdo_dim_element('latitude', -90, 90, .5)),
    null); -- add metadata after all rows are updated to null srid
```

or, if for some reason you hate to insert and then update, there is another way:

```
insert into granule_cartesian
select  granule, mdsys.sdo_geometry (t.shape.SDO_GTYPE, null, t.shape.SDO_POINT, t.shape.SDO_ELEM_INFO, t.shape.SDO_ORDINATES)
from    granule t
where   platform = 'ZZ'; -- granule has a few other columns...
```

in that case you can have a row in user_sdo_geom_metadata table and even a spatial index before you insert rows into granule_cartesian.

hth. good luck.

Comment: Its been a LONG time.... So, SRID = null is a cartesian shape, SRID != null is a geodetic shape. Doing that code: `SDO_GEOMETRY(SDO_UTIL.TO_WKTGEOMETRY(shape), null)` is the only way to strip an SRID from a shape. By going to the raw points and back to a shape, you erase any concept of what coordinate system the shape was in. You can go the OTHER way, cartesian -> geodetic with `SDO_CS.TRANSFORM(geom => shape, to_srid => 8307 )` but `to_srid` will absolutely not take null. As for `set t.shape.sdo_srid = null`, it doesn't work. You can CHANGE the srid this way, but you cannot null it out...

Comment: ... At least `t.shape.sdo_srid = null` did not work in the version of Oracle I had at the time. Which I believe was some version of 11. Oracle is VERY peculiar in that it won't allow you to go GEODETIC -> CARTESIAN. As a side note, I was able to do it in batches as described above. However, even in cartesian coordinates, we couldn't even begin to approach the performance we now get using Postgres and PostGIS.